# How can I selectively print text and graphs in IPython?

Tags: pdf, ipython

So I'm building a report generating project and want to print/save to pdf the graphs and potentially also the text to explain them.

At the moment I can only print the entire IPython notebook and don't want to bog down the report with the code.

Is there a way to add multiple outputs into one pdf? Or should I just generate all of my graphs with one script and then just print just that?

I can live without the text explanations as the titles should be self explanatory, but would be better to have them in. Happy to add any and all modules necessary.

Comment: If you use nbconvert to convert the notebook to PDF, you can make [custom templates](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html) to e.g. exclude the code cells from the output.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to thank you for this!